# AWS lambda as REST client

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Is it possible to use lambda as a REST client?

I want to have a lamda function which polls data from a REST api?

For example:

Poll weather data from a weather data service every second?

Or is lambda not a good solution for that?

Comment: Every second?  No, AWS Lambda is a terrible solution for that.  Less frequent polling (say 10 minutes) - great solution.  What are your real requirements?

Comment: I want to read a "stream" of data and I want to analyze it. But I cant push the data. I have to read the data from a REST api. Every second is maybe too fast. But every ten seconds or every minute would be great. I can setup a smal EC2 instance. But I wanted to use a solution with less maintenance like serverless.

Comment: Ultimately to use AWS Lambda this way you'll need a Cloudwatch Event that triggers the Lambda.  These are 1 minute resolution at a minimum.  Depending on how long your Lambda runs each time I'd be concerned about the cost - Lambda can get very expensive very fast.  I get the benefit of serverless but Lambda may not be the right solution.  A small EC2 instance is very cheap but yes, it requires maintenance.

Comment: Which service would you recommend to use for those use cases? Container?

Comment: Take a look at Kinesis - it has a wide number of ways to use it and it's pretty much designed for what you want to do.  You could roll your own on an EC2 also but, again, there is some system maintenance there.  You'll need to figure out where your data goes with Kinesis but that's usually not bad.

Comment: I guess AWS API gateway is what you should be looking at. Amazon API Gateway tightly integrates with AWS Lambda to allow you to create completely server-less APIs.

Comment: @stdunbar Yes I looked at Kinesis. But there is the same problem. You have to push the data to Kinisis. Kinisis has no polling function.

Comment: @Shantanu API Gateway is a good solution for the opposite way. It is good to push data to lambda functions. But I get my data from an api. So I have to poll the data.

Comment: AWS Fargate might be an option. It allows you to run a "Serverless" Docker container. As you need the process to be running continually that might be the best fit.